# Basic Kohana Routing

Tags: php, kohana

I'm new with Kohana and finding their documentation to be lacking (lots of incomplete writings, lots of broken links, etc.). I just want to create a route like so:

```
Route::set('test1', 'blah/<id>')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'Blah',
        'action'     => 'foo',
));
```

So if the URL is localhost/blah/8342342 it will run through this controller and action. The problem is I get a 404 error. If I change the URI in the Route::set to be `blah/foo/<id>` it works fine. I only want the /blah/ directory though, not 'blah/foo'. Is this possible or do you need to have both the controller and action in the URL?

Another question, does the first directory in your URI (in this case /blah) HAVE to match the controller name? For example, if the first directory in the URI is "blah/", does that mean my controller must be named "Blah.php"? From my tests it seems that this is the case, but I don't know why it would be set up that way. What if I wanted the URI "contact/" to go through controller Blah?

Comment: It is very possible, and it should work just as you described: by specifying defaults. You say '.. it will run through this controller and action.'  Have you actually checked that? If the right action is started, the routing has done it's job and the problem is somewhere else. If not, check if there's another route defined earlier that could also match the url `/blah/8342342`.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. It was the 'default' route that was intercepting it. I moved my 'test1' route above it and it works. Thanks for your help. I realize that was a pretty stupid oversight on my part =)